# Is Kenobi retconning episode IV A New Hope? (*Spoiler Alert*)

Tags: star-wars, obi-wan-kenobi-2022

In the first *Star Wars* film (retroactively retitled *A New Hope*), Vader says to Obi-Wan Kenobi "When I left you, I was but the learner. Now *I* am the master."

Yet, Vader and Kenobi duke it out in episode 3 of *Obi-Wan Kenobi* ten years after their duel on Mustafar (during which Obi-Wan made schnitzel out of Anakin). During their encounter in *Obi-Wan Kenobi*, Vader has the upper hand throughout, and Kenobi only escapes through someone else's intervention. This occurs chronologically seven or eight years before the original *Star Wars* film.

Is this a retcon of the original Star Wars movie, since Vader clearly masters Kenobi almost a decade before episode IV?

Comment: So many retcons in the *Star Wars* universe right now, what’s one more?

Comment: Yes, it's a retcon.

Comment: Holding off on posting an answer until the show finishes, but it seems like he's specifically talking about when he parted ways with Obi-Wan, right? Not when he last saw him?

Comment: It is not a retcon IMO, it is bending continuity a bit. The whole interaction with Leia as well... "General Kenobi, you served my father in the clone wars" ... why not "General Kenobi you saved me once before".

Comment: Presumably Vader thinks he left Kenobi *before* the duel on Mustafar, as he didn't really "leave" Kenobi then — he laid on the ground, without enough functioning limbs to go anywhere unassisted, as Kenobi walked off. The encounter in episode 3 of *Obi-wan Kenobi* is similar — Vader is blocked from approaching Kenobi when the fire is re-ignited by Tara Durith, who then helps Kenobi escape, presumably unseen.

Comment: @Skooba:  Maybe Leia realizes that others will view the hologram and there are reasons that her abduction as a child or Kenobi's involvement in her rescue are not or should not be public.

Comment: They have to duel again and Kenobi has to win. Otherwise their dialog in Ep IV makes no sense anymore...2 episodes left as of this writing...

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I think you have the kernel of a thoughtful answer there, although Vader in episode 3 of *OWK* for 100% saw Kenobi moments earlier when they were bashing light sabers together.

Comment: I certainly think obi wan and vader will duke it out in the last episode where 'spoiler alert' -  obi wan shows his mastery

Comment: @Lexible oh yeah Vader saw Kenobi, they had a whole

Comment: @tilley31 Dum dum _duuuuuuuuum_

Comment: *Why won’t he say anything, as motionless as a statue? Nineteen years. **Nineteen years since I left him to die.** Nineteen years of reliving his corruption every night in my dreams. What does he look like under that mask? What does he see through those ruby lenses?* - Time of Death by Cavan Scott

Comment: Looks like the fifth part of the series gives you your answer...

Comment: ... and the sixth even more so.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Called it!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is Kenobi retconning episode IV A New Hope?

Not for this scene.

In the final Kenobi episode, Kenobi clearly defeats Vader so it definitely satisfies the "I was but the learner" line.

However, once again Kenobi leaves Vader so the "When I left you" line is still retconned.  But keep in mind that Revenge of the Sith had already retconned this line because Kenobi left Vader after their fight on Mustafar.

Comment: I don't think there's any need to get stuffy over who left who in the sense of "who literally walked away while the other person watched them go". You wouldn't call me a liar if I said that I left my employer just because I work remote and did not literally leave the building. Anakin certainly left the master-padawan relationship.

Comment: +1 So you are saying the *Kenobi* folks nerd-sniped me? (I will likely accept your answer when I see the final episodes.)